# laravel 5.2 auth Conditions for email verify

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i want to edit auth and add Additional Conditions

for check user for active or ...

where can edit authcontroller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a `status` column in `users` table to mark the user as active or inactive.

To check the user status during login you need to modify this file:

```
project_folder\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php
```

You can change `validateLogin()` method. I assume, for active user the status code is `1` and `0` for inactive user. Your code should look like this:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required', 'status' => 1,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Not work on Laravel 5.2. You can add this: 
`$this->loginUsername() => 'required|exists:users,username,status,1'`

Answer (score 1):

In Auth\AuthController.php, add this function ( I assume the column name for user status is "is_active" ):

```
public function authenticated($request, $user) {
        if ($user->is_active != 'Y') {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect('login')->withErrors([
                $this->loginUsername() => 'Your '.$this->loginUsername().' is not active. Please contact Administrators'
            ]);
        }else {
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have added this method but its not working. I'm using laravel 5.2.